# Bokeh Server: embedding animated chart (get hold of an active session)

Tags: bokeh

I have embedded animated plot sample into a web page, that works fine. After restarting the animated.py plot script the `bokeh_modelid="71dcea49-64c3-42d3-bac1-373f780fe2fd"` keeps changing, so I need to modify the embed script part in HTML.

How to get `bokeh_modelid="XYZ"` point to a fix string, so embed script doesn't have to be modified each time animated script is restarted?

```
<html> 
<body> 
<h2>Simple Embed Example</h2> 
<p>Here is my plot:</p> 
<p> 
<script src="http://localhost:5006//bokeh/embed.js" 
bokeh_plottype="serverconn" bokeh_docid="3980adc2-f1c8-4207-906b-dde7d636ac82" 
bokeh_ws_conn_string="ws://localhost:5006/bokeh/sub" 
bokeh_docapikey="43274608-8c07-4d76-9d57-df2da7d14212" 
bokeh_root_url="http://localhost:5006/" 
bokeh_modelid="71dcea49-64c3-42d3-bac1-373f780fe2fd" 
bokeh_modeltype="Plot" async="true"></script>
</p>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it related to programming?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that new model is created each the animated.py is restarted.

Answers and suggestions to this question are at Bokeh forum:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/Rt7UCnCyHrA